# how to properly mock $location.url() using jasmine and karma

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my actual js, I am trying to get query params from the url like this:

```
let string = $location.url().split('string=')[1];
```

and equating it to a scope variable:

```
$scope.string = string;
loadAnotherFunction(); // called next
```

and I wrote the following as a test:

```
let $rootScope, $compile, $location;
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('module.directives'
, function($provide){
    let url = '/test/url';
    const location = {
        url: jasmine.createSpy('url').and.returnValue(url)
    };
    $provide.value('$location', location);
}));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(['$compile', '$location', '$rootScope',
function(_$compile_, _$location_ ,_$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $location = _$location_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}]));

<!-- another beforeEach which compiles the element & scope and digests and applies scope-->

it('replaces directive correctly', function(){
        expect(element.html()).toContain('div');
});
```

But I keep getting

> ReferenceError: $location is not defined

and this is not very explanatory so I'm not sure what the issue is here. I believe i injected this properly and it has access to it (because it would have thrown the "unknownLocationProvider <- location" error), so what could be the problem?

Comment: in what line u get error? Cause this is not angularjs error - variable was not declared. Beside this u either use $provide.value or jasmine spy - using both looks strange.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It doesn't say what line exactly in the error msgs, which is why I'm confused. And I tried both seperately and then together - I'm not used to testing with karma so I wasn't sure of the rules

Comment: @PetrAveryanov the error is from karma, which is used to test angularjs